# How to split complex lines?

Tags: qgis, editing

I want to edit some complex polylines, which I imported from my GPS. These polylines have many vertices and are selfintersecting many times.
When I try to split these lines using the 'Split Features'-command the line is split on every selfintersect and not only where I draw the cuting line. What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?
I'm using QGIS 1.8 on Windows8 (64).

Answer (score 2):

This is a know bug: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/4087

Unfortunately, noone came up with a solution yet. For GPS Tracks, you might try to clean and cut them with Qlandkarte GT.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So lets hope for QGIS 1.9 ;)
I've tried out Qlandkarte GT and in combination with QGIS it's doing want I searched for. Tank you!